# Use variables value as a type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to use a variable as a type. For example, I declare a variable:

```
private readonly gridCol = 'grid-column';
private readonly sortCol = 'sort-column';
```

Now I can use the variable in functions instead of "hard coding" it:

```
return this.grid.querySelector(
      `${this.gridCol}[data-role=selection]`
    ) as gridSelectionColumn<T> | undefined;
    }
```

No problems. But I would like to use the variables I declared as the return type of below function, instead of hardcoding it, or use another variable with same name :

```
  private getColumnTypeName(): 'sort-column' | 'grid-column' {
    return this.sortable ? this.sortCol : this.gridCol;
  }
```

Since this obviously does not work:

```
 private getColumnTypeName(): this.sortCol | this.gridCol {
        return this.sortable ? this.sortCol : this.gridCol;
      }
```

Which will see the retun type as new declaration and return the following errors:

*

> All declarations of 'sortCol' must have identical modifiers.ts(2687)
> Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property
> 'sortCol' must be of type '"sort-column"', but here has type
> 'any'.ts(2717)

- 

Whats the best way to handle this kind of situation, syntax wise? The code is working as it is, but does not seem correct when I have to hardcode the return with the same valuable I have stored in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define string enums and use it like below

```
enum Direction {
  SORT_COLUMNN = "sort-column",
  GRID_COLUMNN = "grid-column",
}

private readonly gridCol = Direction.SORT_COLUMNN;
private readonly sortCol = Direction.GRID_COLUMN;

private getColumnTypeName(): Direction {
    return this.sortable ? this.sortCol : this.gridCol;
}
```

or use an object with [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums)

```
const Direction = {
  SORT_COLUMNN: "sort-column",
  GRID_COLUMNN: "grid-column",
} as const;

private readonly gridCol = Direction.SORT_COLUMNN;
private readonly sortCol = Direction.GRID_COLUMN;

private getColumnTypeName(): typeof Direction[keyof typeof Direction]; {
    return this.sortable ? this.sortCol : this.gridCol;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following syntax to look up the type on your class (you didn't give the class name, so i'm calling it "Example"):

```
class Example {
  private readonly gridCol = 'grid-column';
  private readonly sortCol = 'sort-column';

  private getColumnTypeName(): Example["sortCol"] | Example["gridCol"] { 
    return this.sortable ? this.sortCol : this.gridCol;
  }
}
```

If sortCol and gridCol were public, then it would also be possible to do `this["sortCol"]`, but that doesn't work with private members

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=34&pln=7&pc=41#code/MYGwhgzhAECiAeYC2AHEBTaBvAUNf0KATgJYBuYALpkemACYD2AdiAJ7QDmp9AwoyGgBeaAHJuJegFpgAgK5JmogNx4CxclRp0mrDhEZFK-QSNEGjM%20YpU41%20DRWrQLlMACMMw6ADMwICHRVe0JSJ0xOdGNrZgAVNhR0ADlkdAAKAEoALjhEVAwAbQAiVxMigF1oAB9c5DR0Yok%20AQrsEIJoWko5ImZoSgALEggAOlcPLwB%20fqHR0oFoHMHhkaaTVQ6AXzsOxy1%209AhKTLaOjoB6c-6EzEYfaAoQOUxhsSarJ5tqsVcPhSV2gRZMwjg9-M9vMtRpFop84jcUkh0hkNgRtpsgA)